# How to pass headers from AWS API Gateway

Tags: httprequest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lumen

I'm passing the addition key-value pairs from lambda function, same as mention in [aws labs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/4920d93a5f67bb445be57b8e1aa88967a036e0e3/blueprints/nodejs/index.js#L66). Then in API Gateway I have setup the body mapping templates in integration request. ([Check this](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1509020092.png)).

But when request goes to the endpoint (PHP) then I'm unable to get any data. It is empty array `print_r($_REQUEST);`

I checked cloudWatch this is what it is showing.

`Endpoint request body after transformations: 
{ "userData" : "{"city":"USA","Name":"Sanket","id":3}" }`

Additional info - 
When I print `print_r($_REQUEST);` then it is empty array but when I print `$request->getContent();` it shows all the data.

**UPDATE - I**
[Additional information here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266525)

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you have setup body mapping template in integration request. If you want to integrate a response then you should setup it in integration response, not in integration request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have setup the integration response. But my point is the parameter pass (that is setup in integration request) should be accessible at the endpoint (the application hosted on ec2) at the first place. you are right that I have to setup the integration response but the endpoint is not receiving the parameter that I'm passing from the integration request.